# How can I apply a style to a concrete Combobox item?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, visual-studio, combobox

I am trying to implement a Combobox containing all the installed Fonts which shows every Item with the corresponding font.
Is there any way to style a single Item of a ComboBox using C# in Windows Forms?
Thank you!

Comment: ["Owner Drawn"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawmode.aspx) is the keyword you were looking for.

Comment: you can view this topic : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2699/FontComboBox-a-font-listing-combo-box-for-NET

Comment: and also : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/318174/Creating-a-WYSIWYG-font-ComboBox-using-Csharp

Comment: Thank you very much, @theB ! That really helped!